# Почему в AsyncTask не работает Http?

Tags: android

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Вот мой код

```
    @Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    myLocation();
    return null;
}

void myLocation(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String lat=Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            String lot=Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            myRegister(lat,lot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, locationListener, context.getMainLooper());
}

void myRegister(final String lat, final String lot){
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try{
        imei=tm.getDeviceId();
        operator=tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
        number=tm.getLine1Number();
        location_long=lot;
        location_lat=lat;
        language=Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

        //test
        imei= String.valueOf(200);
        location_long= String.valueOf(0);
        location_lat= String.valueOf(0);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("register",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isRegister=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("register",false);
        radius=sharedPreferences.getString("radius","");
        charCount=sharedPreferences.getString("charCount","");
        postUpdateTime=sharedPreferences.getString("postUpdateTime","");
        type=sharedPreferences.getString("type","");

        if (!isRegister){
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("imei",imei)
                    .put("operator", operator)
                    .put("number", number)
                    .put("location_long", location_long)
                    .put("location_lat", location_lat)
                    .put("language", language);

            String json=HttpRequest.postRequest("http://5.45.112.166/register.xml")
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .addParam("",jsonObject.toString())
                    .getResponse().getResponseText();

            JSONObject jsonTemp=new JSONObject(json);

            radius=jsonTemp.getString("CONFIG_ADV_RADIUS");//Радиус
            charCount=jsonTemp.getString("CONFIG_POST_CHARS_COUNT");//Кол-во символов в посте
            postUpdateTime=jsonTemp.getString("CONFIG_POSTS_RENEW");//период обновления в минутах
            type=jsonTemp.getString("CONFIG_POST_SORT_TYPE");//Типа

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=context.getSharedPreferences("register",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences2.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("register",true);
            editor.putString("radius", radius);
            editor.putString("charCount",charCount);
            editor.putString("postUpdateTime",postUpdateTime);
            editor.putString("type",type);
            editor.commit();
        }
        myPosts();
    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void myPosts(){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("imei",imei)
                .put("location_long",location_long)
                .put("location_lat",location_lat)
                .put("radius",radius)
                .put("sorting", type)
                .put("page", 0)
                .put("postsOnPage", 10)
                .put("lastPostId", 0);

        String posts=HttpRequest.postRequest("http://5.45.112.166/posts.xml")
                .addParam("",jsonObject.toString()).getResponse().getResponseText();

        jsonPosts=new JSONArray(new JSONObject(posts).getJSONArray("posts").toString());

    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ошибку получаю на строке

```
            String posts=HttpRequest.postRequest("http://5.45.112.166/posts.xml")
                .addParam("",jsonObject.toString()).getResponse().getResponseText();
```

Почему В AsyncTask Функция в функции не считается как Http функция. Ведь  ней можно использовать функции для Http

Comment: Помогите код исправить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом то деле можно... Мне кажется у тебя проблема в чем то в другом. Раз у тебя выходит ошибка:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Значит данный метод у тебя вызывается еще где то помимо AsyncTask.

А все понятно... Смотри. методом myLocation() ты запускаешь определение локации. И после этого твой AsyncTask() умирает. После которого начинает свою работу LocationListener. Во время работы LocationListener в какое то время (Как только определяется твой LocationListener находит твою позицию)  срабатывает onLocationChanged() и ты шлешь запрос на сервер и причем у тебя далеко не факт, что onLocationChanged() срабатывает тогда, когда твой AsyncTask еще живой. То есть твой onLocationChanged() срабатывает тогда, когда твой AsyncTask уже отработал свою работу и умер и соответсвенно твой метод myPosts() вызывается в главном (UI) потоке)))

Тебе нужно сделать следующее!!! Метод myLocation() запускай в UI потоке, а как только ты поймаешь onLocationChanged(Location location) метод myRegister(lat,lot) запускай в AsyncTask и все будет замечательно!!!

Comment: myLocation() в PreExecute запустить?

Мож пример кода. А точнее модель, где и как должны лежать функции. А то я более менее понял но не все